# Show alert if state is true and if localStorage is true, remove localStorage if browser refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display alert message if the state is true. Also I'm trying to save that state in localStorage and everytime when localStorage is true to display the alert.
On Page refresh, I'm trying to delete the localStorage.

```
import React, {
    useEffect, useState
} from 'react';

const MainClass = () => {

const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setAlert(true);
    if (alert === true) {
        localStorage.setItem('Alert', alert);
    }
}, []);

const test = localStorage.getItem('Alert');

window.onload = function () {
    console.log('TEST on load');
    localStorage.removeItem('Alert');
};

return(
{alert && test === true && (
    <Alert
        message="Messgae"
    />
)}
)
    
};
```

My issue is that I'm not able to display the alert if I add the condition `test === true` and also I'm not able to remove the localStorage on browser refresh

Answer (score 0):

no need to use === just if (alert) works to check for a truthy. Note that what

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setAlert(true);
            if (alert === true) {
                localStorage.setItem('Alert', alert);
            }
      }, []);
```

this basically sets alert true upon rendering the component. Are you sure that this is what you are looking for?

Comment: hmm, i think important approach in my case is to remove the alert from localStorage after refreshing the page